# How get this output using php

Tags: php, excel, csv, upload

Her is the column of CSV file uploaded using php. how can I get the output that shows in the image.
[image: detailed picture]

Comment: Please add the code you have so far with some sample data (in text not an image)

Comment: Please add the code to the question and not as a comment.

Comment: i can not edit my post :( what should i do? do i need to create a new one?

Comment: Voting to close as Too broad. You are asking how to read a CSV file. We have tons of Q&A on that. And you are asking how to compare the values in the CSV against values in a database. And then you are asking how to print this in a certain way. I suggest to break this down into individual problems and see how far you can get on your own. When you are stuck, ask a particular question. Also, it's not clear from the DB screenshot and CSV how the comparison is supposed to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Create new table in Mysql as per the CSV column fields and data types. first id column make  to auto increment column
- After selecting table import using phpmyadmin.